# Can bitcoin address be longer than 35?

Tags: bitcoind, address, address-generation

Can bitcoin address be longer than 35?

Does longer address indicate much lower chance of collision and/or higher security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address):

> A Bitcoin address, or simply address, is an identifier of 26-35 alphanumeric characters

And:

> Some Bitcoin addresses can be shorter than 34 characters (as few as 26)
>   and still be valid. A significant percentage of Bitcoin addresses are
>   only 33 characters, and some addresses may be even shorter. Every
>   Bitcoin address stands for a number. These shorter addresses are valid
>   simply because they stand for numbers that happen to start with
>   zeroes, and when the zeroes are omitted, the encoded address gets
>   shorter.

So no, the length does not imply higher/lower security.

Comment: how about that? https://www.blockchain.com/btc-testnet/address/tb1qcqqpm3y7fzjcmlgu3faun5d543k5yy6jm0lpx3 https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36944/what-are-the-minimum-and-maximum-lengths-of-a-mainnet-bitcoin-address/96778#96778

Comment: This answer is out-of-date.

Though it is true that length does not strictly imply higher/lower security, Segwit addresses can be 14 - 74 with some exceptions (see [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#segwit-address-format))

For Version 0 addresses (`bc1p` prefix) it must be 42 or 62 characters

There is no similar mention of character limits in [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki) for Version 1 addresses (`bc1q` prefix)

Answer (score -1):

Bitcoin address is only a human-readable representation of transaction output scripts. Some kind of scripts do not have standard representations/addresses, but we can create our own "addresses" for them. For example, for any script we can create an "address" by encoding the script in hex form.

These "addresses" can be shorter than 26 symbols or longer than 35