# What are the minimum and maximum length of a Mainnet Bitcoin address?

Tags: address

[The wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address) says that

> A Bitcoin address is an identifier of 26-35 alphanumeric characters.

Is this information up-to-date? Even the Bech32 address `bc1qar0srrr7xfkvy5l643lydnw9re59gtzzwf5mdq` given as an example on the same page  has 42 characters.

Some other Bitcoin mainnet address examples:

- [bc1zqyqsywvzqe](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1zqyqsywvzqe) has 14 characters.
- [bc1qwxlm0dtlgsfv9qqyvv20mu5l82cn59xs20587rh8j6vym77km0vq3xqmca](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/bc1qwxlm0dtlgsfv9qqyvv20mu5l82cn59xs20587rh8j6vym77km0vq3xqmca) has 62 characters.

Before you say that this is duplicate, I know that [What are the minimum and maximum lengths of a Mainnet Bitcoin address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36944/what-are-the-minimum-and-maximum-lengths-of-a-mainnet-bitcoin-address) asks the same question. However, I do not have enough reputation to add a comment there.

Comment: Yep, as @darosior said, you found outdated information on the wiki and our site. As you note, it is essentially a duplicate of the question you mention though. I would propose that we do one of the following: 1. You or someone else posts a new answer on the linked question with the new minimums and maximums. 2. You suggest an edit to the existing answer to add the info. Or 3., you clarify how your new question here differs from the original, e.g. by specifying that this question includes "non-standard" addresses like the 14 character example you identified. What do you think?

Comment: In the first two cases, we would close this question here as a duplicate in favor of the one you linked to. But yeah, we should see that the linked question is updated.

Comment: @Murch I added a new answer to the linked question. As I am not sure about the minimum and maximum length, I cited BIP 173 and I hope that the numbers in BIP 173 are the actual min, max values. Now, this question can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! I've merged the two and upvoted your answer!